# mysql workbench select from other database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench. Now I need to select from other database. e.g.

```
select * from `abcsms`.table1
```

However, because there is a default schema set. It always complain abcsms.abcsms cannot be found. How can I unset the default schema setting in workbench and then let the query run?

Thanks.

Comment: [The first entry of this link might help.](http://bit.ly/1hBzF6G)

Comment: Not a problem - works in MySQL Workbench 6.07

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest MySQL Workbench, then i think you should not getting this type of issue. I am using MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE.

You first open MySQL Workbench, then from menu bar, click on database and then connect. and click on OK button. 
Now you will see a list of all databases.
You just double click on the database which you want to select.
Then your desired database will be selected.

Thanks.